# GDAL function to split large image into specific chunks

Tags: python, image-processing, gdal

I would like to use GDAL if possible to split an image up to 3Gb into 100mb TIFs so that I can do processing on these smaller chunks.  After the processing I would like to reconstruct these images(which will look different) back into their original positions to create one large TIF again.  It seems like I can use ImageMagick to do this but I would like to stick with GDAL if possible.

So, what functions would I use in GDAL to split and then reconstruct chunks? retile.py? polygonize.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the image into chunks/tiles with `gdal2tiles`. You could also split it into parts depending on the amount of pixels for each chunk using [`gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) with the `-srcwin` option. This however would require you to write a bash/batch script to loop through your 30 image chunks.

If your processing does not change the pixel size or spatial position the easiest way to mosaick them is to use [`gdal_merge`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html).

Comment: [gdal2tiles](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) link since I am only allowed to use 2 links in my answer.

Comment: I was thinking about using gdal2tiles but the higher numbered folders have thousands of tiny images in them and the lower numbered images which have around 20-50 photos would probably work but they are only around 60Kb.  I would assume that I would lose quality when processing these larger images that are small in size.  That's why I was hoping to be able to split the original into smaller tiles that don't lose quality.

Comment: Then I suggest using gdal_translate with the -srcwin option and either working with a bash/batch script or python - as suggested here: [FOSS method to split raster into smaller chunks](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14712/foss-method-to-split-raster-into-smaller-chunks)